# Overflow property not hiding traversing dots

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of dots that I want to move to one side of a box, and disappear when they leave the region of the box, then come back in from the other side of the box. This part works fine, but for whatever reason the overflow property does not seem to be kicking in on the box and the dots are not hiding when the leave the area of the box. As you can see, the box class specifies the overflow property to be hidden:

```
.box {
  height: 380px;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The rest of the code can be found on [this](http://codepen.io/DITTODITTO/pen/zqoyjr) pen. The dots that I am referring to are located in the third box.

Comment: The `.dot` elements are absolutely positioned, meaning they are not calculated as part of the document flow, so the `overflow: hidden` on the parent has no effect on them at all. There's no workaround for this, you would need to animate the dots *without* using `position: absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving `position relative` to the box container. You will need to readjust the position of the dots inside, but this will fix the overflow visibility of the dots.

**Box CSS**

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 380px;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The positioning of the dots will have to change as they are now relative to their direct parent:

**Old Dot CSS**

```
#box1 .dot:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 182.5px;
  margin-left: calc(33% / 2 - 70px);
}
```

**New Dot CSS**

```
#box1 .dot:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 182.5px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 70px);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! The margin-left calculation was using the percents based on the view width, but I wanted it to be for the box, so it solves another one of my questions. Thanks!